# Get last invoice date and first branch user visit (first invoice date)

Tags: mysql, sql

invoices Table

| id | date | branch_id | patient_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-03 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-09-08 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-09-15 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-09-16 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 2021-09-17 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 2021-09-19 | 2 | 3 |

end result

| id | date | branch_id | patient_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-03 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-09-16 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-09-19 | 1 | 3 |

get last invoice date with first branch user vistt(first invoice date)

I use this to get last invoice for each patient

```
SELECT patient_id ,max(date) 
            FROM  invoices
            GROUP BY patients.id
```

how to get with it first branch user visit

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using?

Comment: sql server and mysql are two different products. Which one do you use? And is it possible that all you need is min(date)?

Comment: i  use mysql in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
select patient_id 
       , max(date) lastinvoicedate
       , first_Value(branch_id) over (order by date asc) firstbranch
from tablename
group by patient_id
```

Comment: this query what i need realy but  i get error first_value does not exist

Comment: @AbdulrhmanElroupy  window functions only available from MYSQL 8 and above. which version are you using?

Comment: MySQL Version 5.7.35